# net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED on SSL turned on Chrome and edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ssl

I'm loading about 200 files by code:

```
jQuery.ajax({url:'markery/'+pliki[z], success: function(xml){
```

Without SSL all working ok but when I turn on certificate on chrome and edge I get error:

> GET https://myfile.xml net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Some files are not loaded and it happens on random one time those files later different ones. Can anyone help me I have no idea why chrome/edge block connection and how to prevent this.

Comment: It's your server closing the connection, not the browser or JS. Most likely because you're flooding so many requests to the server from the same IP that you're triggering DDOS or intrusion prevention systems.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan So it's not the timeout AJAX uses (usually 30 secs)?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan If it would be true then I would get like first 50 or 100 files but I didn't get like 10,34,65,150 each time different and it didn't happening on firefox. I asked server admin he checked logs they didn't block anything

Comment: @Teemu same if this would be timeout then still it would block all files after some time. It not the case since last files on list are loaded.

Comment: As already commented - the problem is on the server side (or somewhere in the middle). Since nothing is known except the client side code and error one can only wildly speculate what the reason for the problem is. In any case it is out of control of the client, so one cannot help here just based on the provided information.

Comment: Copied whole webpage to another provider error changed to: GET https://myfile.xml net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.